# How to implement binary TCP protocol

Tags: networking, tcp

I created a number of TCP client / server applications in past, that were always using very simple text based protocols, either text messages separated by new line or Xml streams.

Now I am creating a simple protocol for a game server that would mostly exchange Vector information and handle some simple RPC calls with clients. Because it's going to be a game server I really want to it to be super fast and lightweight. For this reason I decided to implement it as a binary protocol (see [Are binary protocols dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525188/are-binary-protocols-dead) for some more information on what I mean).

I have a rough idea how to do that, but before I start working on it I would like to confirm that this approach is actually going to work and if there isn't any better, commonly used one. I never implemented binary TCP protocols in past.

I am going to send all information in "packets of information" which I just call "datagrams". Another important constant within the protocol is the size of floating point numbers in bytes, which I just call `BLOCK_SIZE`. I am going to use multiple languages (client will be C#, while server is C++) and I need to make sure that all platforms (x86, x64) will have same sized numbers within datagrams.

First information that server sends to client is going to be a single byte (`sizeof(char)`) containing the value of `BLOCK_SIZE` just to make sure that floating point numbers (I am using `double` because it's big enough for my purposes) are going to take same amount of bytes on both server and client. Then a stream of "datagrams" follows until end of communication channel.

Layout of datagram is:

```
Size in bytes / name                  Description
BLOCK_SIZE / type            Type of datagram (for internal purposes I need to figure out what I am actually going to process - I could probably create header instead that would describe it in details, but for my purposes one `double` can contain all possible types I will use)
unsigned BLOCK_SIZE / size   Length of datagram - number of bytes that will follow. I just hope I will never need to send a single datagram that would be bigger tham maximum value of unsigned double :P
size / data                  Data that are contained within datagram, I will process them based on what `type` they will be.
```

I suppose that for receiving I would just always create a buffer big as `size` announced by either side would be and keep pushing data into it, unless I get them all. And then I can start processing another datagram.

I believe this should work as long as client and server always send correct data with not a single byte being wrong, extra or missing. I don't know if TCP is reliable enough, or if I need to implement some error checking as well. I have no idea how.

I only need to transfer huge amount of arrays of floating point numbers, eventually some very simple strings, but I don't really need to care about that right away. Is this a right approach or should I do it in a different way?

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, maybe Protocol Buffers is your solution? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: avoiding wheel reinvention was one of reasons why I asked here :P

Comment: Your title gave the impression that you want to create your *own* protocol...

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the word "datagram" if you are going to use TCP transport; a datagram is usually associated with UDP transfers.

TCP is reliable then you don't need extra CRCs or things like that.

you could implement i.e. a very simple binary stream protocol where 
every data unit is prepended by 2 bytes; the first one indicating its class and the second one indicating its length.

```
                   class     length
unsigned byte        1          1
         byte        2          1
unsigned short       3          2
         short       4          2
unsigned int         5          4
         int         6          4
        ...

array unsigned byte  1          1 * #elements 
array          byte  2          1 * #elements
array unsigned short 3          2 * #elements 
array          short 4          2 * #elements
array unsigned int   5          4 * #elements 
array          int   6          4 * #elements
        ...
```

the representation of the **length** variable (one byte) limits the total size of the data element to 255 bytes
the representation of the **class** variable (one byte) limits the total # of classes to 255

remember when using TCP you must handle a "flow" of data that is independent of the size of the transmitted data units. You should not make assumptions about the size of the received packets; a data unit could be very well split in more than one TCP packet even if it fits on a single one

i.e. the sequence
0x01-0x01-0x33 
is a data unit that could represent i.e the ASCII char "3"

you might think there is too much overhead, but transferring a single byte is the worst case scenario, the overhead gets smaller when the data unit gets bigger. Also consider this is the price to pay for not being dependent on a predefined higher level data structure.