# Creating the secrets system from the LoZ Oracle games

Tags: java, python, game-engine

Recently I have been replaying the Legend of Zelda Oracle of Seasons and Oracle of Ages games and the secret codes caught my attention. I now would like to recreate this in Python or Java to see how it works.

The problem is, I cannot find a way to do it. How would you make an encoding system that

1. Relies on the first "link" code you typed it (secret to labrynna or holodrum, as it is named in the games) so you cannot steal a code from someone else;
2. Detects typos. If you type fobaz instead of foobar, it detects that the code is wrong;
3. Can store a bunch (a decent amount) of info. And it's s also between 5-20 characters, as in the games (this is not necessary, but would be nice)

Note: I am not trying to create a generator for the Oracle games, just some code to generate and read secrets that look like the ones from the Oracle games

The programming scope of this question is how to encode and decode information using a system that mimics the secret codes in the Oracle games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a form of serialization + encoding, I expect.

You basically need to generate a byte array containing the various secret values (this is how most [binary protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645009/binary-protocols-v-text-protocols) are written), then encode each byte into a corresponding character (or more) so that the output "string" is readable. Here's a sample of how you'd serialize the data into a byte array in Python:

### Player Info

```
player_name = "Robert"

player_stats = {
    "health": 200,
    "mana": 150,
    "has_sword": True,
    "has_arrows": False,
    "has_shovel": True,
    "dungeon1_complete": True
}
```

### Set up Serialization info

```
# If these can be greater than 255, they must be stored across multiple bytes - extra work
byte_attribs = ["health", "mana"]

bit_attribs = ["has_sword", "has_arrows", "has_shovel", "dungeon1_complete"]

player_name_max_length = 7
byte_attrib_offset = player_name_max_length
bit_attrib_offset = byte_attrib_offset + len(byte_attribs)

secret_storage = bytearray(bit_attrib_offset + len(bit_attribs))

assert(len(player_name) <= player_name_max_length)
```

### Perform Serialization

```
# Serialize Player Name
secret_storage[:player_name_max_length] = player_name.rjust(player_name_max_length)

# Serialize attributes:
for idx, attrib in enumerate(byte_attribs):
    secret_storage[byte_attrib_offset + idx] = player_stats[attrib]

for idx, attrib in enumerate(bit_attribs):
    byte_offset = idx // 8  # attribs 0-7 go in byte 0, etc.
    bit_offset = idx % 8

    # Bit manipulation examples: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation
    current_byte = bit_attrib_offset + byte_offset
    if player_stats[attrib]:
        mask = 1 << bit_offset
        secret_storage[current_byte] = secret_storage[current_byte] | mask
    else:
        mask = ~(1 << bit_offset)
        secret_storage[current_byte] = secret_storage[current_byte] & mask
```

### Retrieve individual values

```
print "Storage array encoded as ascii:", secret_storage

# Access name:
print "Name:", secret_storage[:player_name_max_length].lstrip()
# >>> Name: Robert

# Access byte values:
attrib_idx = byte_attribs.index("mana")
print "Mana level:", secret_storage[byte_attrib_offset + attrib_idx]
# >>> Mana level: 150

# Access bit flags:
attrib_idx = bit_attribs.index("dungeon1_complete")
print "Completed Dungeon 1:", bool(secret_storage[bit_attrib_offset + (attrib_idx // 8)] & (1 << attrib_idx % 8))
# >>> Completed Dungeon 1: True
```

Comment: It hit me at work that serialization had to play a part in the process. This great for what I plan to do. I will wait a day to see if any more answers come in before accepting.