# wcf serialization over http and nettcp binding

Tags: wcf

From MSDN, I have read that TCP uses binary encoding.

Does it mean that tcp binding will use binary serialization and http binding will use xml serialization ?

I have been struggling to get a clear picture of what happens after the WCF service operation method returns data and  what is fed to the transport layer to return the data to client?
Also how does it differ (If it differs) with http binding and tcp binding ?

Please help me .

Comment: Never mind . I found these two links which answered my questions. http://forums.asp.net/t/1864812.aspx/1          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364581/binary-vs-text-protocols

Comment: My questions have been answered thanks.